# Adding a custom filter provider to Spring Boot ObjectMapper

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson

We have a requirement to filter certain fields of POJOs from serialization in our Spring Boot application based on security and other criteria. We implemented this by writing a custom filter and adding it to a FilterProvider and ultimately adding it to the ObjectMapper.

The default ObjectMapper (primary) was already taken by a library we depend on (no hopes of changing that). There were also a number of other Spring beans of type ObjectMapper that were interfering with our effort to add this filter. So we did a hack by implementing a custom `BeanPostProcessor`, inspecting all beans of type ObjectMapper and adding our filter to it. It worked - not the most ideal solution but got us what we wanted.

Now after upgrading from 1.5.7 to 1.5.12 this has stopped working. I can still debug and verify that the `BeanPostProcessor` is being called and the filter being added, but at runtime the serialization throws error saying filter is not found for the JsonFilter id specified.

Any suggestion on what changed that could have stopped this hack from working or how to get this right?

Regards,
Arnab.